# JS TinyMCE is saving full page

Tags: javascript, html, tinymce

I've got this problem with TinyMCE, that when I submit the content to the database, it is saved with `<!doctype...<html>.....<body>`. I saw some posts about removing the fullpage plugin, but in my case, I dont have that. So I tried to delete it to be sure, and refresh my browser cache, and I still got the same problem. I just want to save the HTML in between the body tags.

I submit the tinyMCE like a normal form with the textarea having the POST name and with a submit button.

```
 <form method="post" action="/profile/edit/profile/text">

        {{ csrf_field() }}

        <input type="hidden" name="text2" value="1">

        <textarea id="tinymce-editor" name="text">{!! $profile -> text !!}</textarea>

        <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-check"></i>Lagre</button>

    </form>
```

.

```
/**
 * @return mixed
 *
 * Process profile text
 */
public function postEditText() {

    // Sanitize HTML
    $html = $this -> sanitizeHTML(Input::get('text'));

    // Validate
    $val = Validator::make([
        'text' => $html
    ], [
        'text' => 'sometimes|max:50000'
    ]);

    if ($val -> fails()) {
        return $this -> backWithErrors($val);
    }

    // Update
    Auth::user() -> profile() -> update([
        'text' => $html
    ]);

    return $this -> backWithSuccess('Profilteksten ble lagret!');

}
```

.

```
/**
 * @param $html
 * @return string
 *
 * HTML sanitizer
 */
private function sanitizeHTML($html) {

    // Disable entity loader
    libxml_disable_entity_loader(false);

    // New DOM doc
    $d = new \DOMDocument();
    $d -> loadHTML($html);

    // Script tags
    $st = $d -> getElementsByTagName('script');
    $l = $st -> length;

    // Remove
    for ($i = 0; $i < $l; $i++) {
        $st -> item($i) -> parentNode -> removeChild($st -> item($i));
    }

    return $d -> saveHTML();

}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So what code are you using to extract the content from TinyMCE and save it to the database?  If you don't have the fullpage plugin installed a call to getContent() will only get what is between the body tags.  Without seeing the code in question all we will be doing is providing you guesses.

Comment: I'm not using any code to extract anything. Just a normal form with a textarea that is replaced by tinyMCE. The form is submitted like a normal form (no AJAX, just a submit button). I can update the post with the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to have code that make a new `DOMDocument` and then loads HTML into it.

If you log the result of `Input::get('text')` what do you get?

Perhaps your code in `sanitizeHTML()` is what is creating the complete HTML document?

According to the manual for `DOMDocument` it "Represents an entire HTML or XML document; serves as the root of the document tree."  If that is the case I suspect that is what is creating your entire document - not TinyMCE.

Comment: Damn, you are absolutely right. Thank you! Do you know how I can get rid of this? I need to strip the `<script>` tags away, thats why I went with DOMDocument.

Is there a way of just loading the given HTML instead of if adding the whole `<!doctype...` etc?

Comment: Never mind, I found the solution.
Using this instead: `$d -> loadHTML($html, LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);`

But thank you!